# Getting IP addresses of the PC's available on wifi network in android

Tags: wifi, ip-address

I am able to establish connection between android and PC via Wi-fi. But this is done by hard coding the the IP address of the PC (server) in the android program. But I wanted to get IP addresses of the PC's available on the Wi-fi network programmatically. So please let me know how to scan for PC's on the network and get their respective IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you not multicast a UDP packet on the network which the server listens for and responds to with a packet containing the ip address of the server in order to set up the connection?

You should be able to find help on that topic, with some options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455755/network-discovery-in-java-multicast-broadcast-java) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072028/multicast-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950715/udp-broadcast-in-java)

Comment: This really great:) Sorry i didn't mention in the question. But I am working on C#. So i wanted help in C# platform. That is I have server application running in PC using C#.